# npm install can't find file (intermittently) in vagrant running on osx

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant

I'm running npm in an ubuntu vagrant box. When running npm install or installing webpack or webpack-cli or babel core I keep running into the error

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/app/client/node_modules/loader-utils/node_modules/minimist/package.json.3207661308'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

babel core has previously installed in this same setup, but almost every time I run npm install it fails.

I suspect this is todo with file sharing between vagrant and osx or permissions issues. But this setup is the same as another (none nodejs) setup which works flawlessly.

I'm running the latest node 10 and the latest ubuntu/xenial64.

Answer (score 0):

I never found an answer to this. But found a work around by using yum instead of npm. I would recommend using yum over npm in all situations now.